# HTMLCollection .item() and [] Use

Tags: javascript, arrays, htmlcollection

There are 2 ways to get a Node from a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

`collection.item(#)` and `collection[#]`

Now both work equally well. And they do the same thing, but [#] let's you think its an Array, what it isn't.

Is there a real difference in use? Or are there time you should use one over the other?